# absを使用した際のエラー解消方法について

Tags: python

【記載したコード】

```
def max_magnitude(nums):
    return max(abs(num) for num in nums)

print(max([1,5,-500]))
```

【エラー表示内容】

```
bad operand type for abs(): 'list'
```

【詳細】
解答通りのコードを入力

```
def max_magnitude(nums):
    return max(abs(num) for num in nums)
```

その後、自身で出力のためにコードを追加

```
print(max([1,5,-500]))
```

コード自体は合っていると思うのですが
どのような原因が考えられるかご教授いただきたいです。

利用コーディングアプリケーション：PyCharm CE

Comment: コードには問題ないと思います。PyCharm以外の環境ではエラーなく実行できますか？

Comment: せっかく定義した`max_magnitude`を呼んでいないようですが、質問時の転記ミスですか？ エラーは何処か入力の途中で`abs()`に`num`ではなく`nums`をパラメータにしていたのかもしれませんね。

Comment: 参考までに、`max()` はキーワードパラメータ `key` でデータのソートに使う関数を指定できます。`abs(max([1, 5, -500], key=abs))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs()`のパラメータを`num`ではなく`nums`にして、`max_magnitude`を呼ぶように変更して実行すると同様のエラーになったので、入力ミスが原因でしょう。
以下のようになっています。

```
>>> def max_magnitude(nums):
...     return max(abs(nums) for num in nums)
...
>>> print(max_magnitude([1,5,-500]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in max_magnitude
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <genexpr>
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'
>>>
```

`abs()`のパラメータを`s`の付かない`num`にすれば正常に動作しています。

```
>>> def max_magnitude(nums):
...     return max(abs(num) for num in nums)
...
>>> print(max_magnitude([1,5,-500]))
500
>>>
```

まだ発生しているようなら、入力されているプログラムソースを細かく確認してみてください。

Comment: みなさま
ご丁寧にご教授いただきありがとうございます。
完全に初歩的なミスだったのですが、
print(max_magnitude([1,5,-500]))
とすべきところ、
print(max([1,5,-500]))
と誤って表示していたことが原因だったようです。

ご回答大変助かりましたm(_ _)m!!!